# Powershell rename and zipping

Tags: powershell

Need to rename all the files wwithin same directory using powershell

Source files
1234_56789abc_t1_20201_0_4_0.pdf
1234_56788def_t2_20200_0._4_1.pdf

Renamed files
1000_56789abc_tar_2020.pdf
1000_56788def_tar_2020.pdf

Also, need to zip these renamed files into one zip file.. In this i want to extract 4 digits of the year and neglect all the underscores afterwards..

Please help??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Therevis some change in requirement which i have edited and want the solution for that..so please let me know the solution for edited problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$directory = Get-Item -Path 'D:\test\mypdf'

foreach( $file in $directory.GetFiles() ) {

    $newFileName = $file.Name -replace '^(.*_)t\d+(_.*)$', '$1tar$2'
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newFileName -WhatIf | out-null
}

Compress-Archive -Path "$directory\*.*" -DestinationPath "$directory\archive.zip" -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force | out-null
```

Comment: Can you please help in geeting the solution for the same as i have made amendments in the description