# Powershell rename and zip files

Tags: powershell

Need to rename all the files within same directory at once using powershell

Source files:

```
1234_56789abc_t1_20200_0_0_4_0.pdf
1234_56789abc_t1_20181_0_0_4_0.pdf
1234_56788def_t2_20190_0_0_4_1.pdf
```

Renamed files:

```
1000_56789abc_tar_2020.pdf
1000_56789abc_tar_2018.pdf
1000_56788def_tar_2019.pdf
```

Also, need to zip these renamed files into one zip file..

Please help??

I tried this one but its not gettung proper output..any help would be appreciated

```
$directory = Get-Item -Path 'D:\test\mypdf'

foreach( $file in $directory.GetFiles() ) {

    $newFileName = $file.Name -replace '^(.*_)t\d+(_.*)$', '$1tar$2'
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newFileName -WhatIf | out-null
}

Compress-Archive -Path "$directory\*.*" -DestinationPath "$directory\archive.zip" -
```

Comment: Show some effort how you try to solve it yourself instead of asking right away.

Comment: $directory = Get-Item -Path 'D:\test\mypdf'

foreach( $file in $directory.GetFiles() ) {

    $newFileName = $file.Name -replace '^(.*_)t\d+(_.*)$', '$1tar$2'
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newFileName -WhatIf | out-null
}

Compress-Archive -Path "$directory\*.*" -DestinationPath "$directory\archive.zip"

Comment: then you should add your failed attempt.

Comment: and not as comment but in the question

Comment: Done..please help me for the same

Comment: Same question, different person? [Powershell rename and zipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683989/powershell-rename-and-zipping)

Comment: @Boendal can you please help me with the solution for the changes edited in main section as i am not able to get the same

Answer (score 0):

Here this works for me:

```
# inputfiles: 
# 1234_56789abc_t1_2020_0.0.4.0.pdf
# 1234_56788def_t2_2020_0.0.4.1.pdf

$directory = Get-Item -Path 'D:\test\mypdf'

foreach( $file in $directory.GetFiles() ) {

    $newFileName = $file -replace '^[0-9]*_','1000_'
    $newFileName = $newFileName -replace '(_)(?!.*\1).*(\.)(?!.*\1)', '.'
    $newFileName = $newFileName -replace '_t[0-9]+_','_tar_'
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$directory\$newFileName" | out-null
}

Compress-Archive -Path "$directory\*.*" -DestinationPath "$directory\archive.zip"
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with that regex and I don't know what `$1tar2`is supposed to be but with this it works.

The regex:

`^[0-9]*_','_1000` take the digits until `_` and replace it with _1000. I don't know what your rule is so you might change it.

`(_)(?!.*\1).*(\.)(?!.*\1)` is a bit complexer.  `(?!.*\1)` this is the negative lookahead pattern which find the last occurence of whatever you put before in pattern in our case it's `(_)` and `(\.)` . So we are replacing the text between the last `_` and the last `.` with a `.`.

And yeah the last regex should be easy to understand. Replace t followed by any number of numbers and between `_` with `_tar_`

In renaming you have to change the path to: `$directory\$newFileName` otherwise it would end at the path you execute the code (if this is what you want go ahead). Please see that I removed the `Whatif`.

With the compression in your code you shared you have a `-`at the end that would fail the execution (but I think it should be a typo?)

Comment: In this I want t1 and t2 to be converted to tar..1234 to be converted to 1000 and 0.0.4.0/1 to be removed from the renamed file.please help in that??

Comment: @Roofy that is what the code do

Comment: Also i dont know the type of file as well..it can be pdf, TXT anything, etc.please acknowledge that as well

Comment: @Roofy see my edit.

Comment: I have edited the description..can you please help me to know how it would rename these type of files as well..thanks in advance

Comment: In this I want only the first 4 digits of the year like 20200 to be replaced with 2020 and all the _'s after that should be removed..@Boendal can you please help as i have edited the same in question

Comment: Admin, please activate this question again as i am not able to get the correct solution

Comment: @Roofy the question wasn't deactivated because you got your answer but rather because you use 2 accounts to ask the same which is quite a rude behaviour on this website. And that is good it should not be reactivated.

Comment: @Roofy also you are quite a impolite person. I asked you about what you already tried and you copy the solution of the guy who helped you in the other question. So in the end you never tried anything yourself. And therefore you misused my trust and for me that is enough to not help you again. You should be able to solve your problem with my code it's so easy that it's quite boring. Maybe you should try it yourself for once instead only asking for help. And always come forth with new requirements you should really learn to ask and how to solve problems by yourself. Good luck.